# Why is using an alias in the having clause working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a group by and having clause in my query and the having seems to be working fine using an alias. No matter what value I put in, or operator (<, >) it returns the correct result. According to logical query processing this should not work but it does. In addition, even if I put some meaningless string in the count function in the having clause it still works.

I am totally baffled!

```
use TSQL2014;
select
c.categoryname,
count(p.productid) as 'TotalProducts'
from Production.Products p

left join Production.Categories c
on p.categoryid = c.categoryid

group by c.categoryname

--having count(p.productid) > 10 
having count('aaaaaa') > 10

order by 'TotalProducts' desc;
```

Comment: Your query should fail, because of the `order by` clause, because SQL Server does not permit constant values there.

Comment: [It's not.](https://rextester.com/PGU98459)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sure you are well aware of the fact that you can use aliases from the `select` clause in the `order by` clause - that's what the OP has done here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . And you are presumably aware that SQL Server does not allow constants in an `ORDER BY` and that a string delimited by single quotes is a constant value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm well aware of both your points (with the exception of numeric constants) - however this does not raise any errors and seem to return the expected results... [See for yourself.](https://rextester.com/KBEB93520)

Comment: Why are you using quoted identifiers to begin with?
Just use "COUNT(p.ProductId) AS TotalProducts", or enclose in square brackets instead. Why confuse things by making it look like a string constant? It's nothing but confusing, and we don't allow such thing in our SQL Coding Standards.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . When I run it, it returns the expected error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=386d1bd99bfea136fd9d5876fb13b5c6.  Oh, I see, SQL Server figures out that a constant string refers to an alias.  More brokenness.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, it depends on the content of the constant value. If it matches a column name or alias in the select clause SQL Server will ignore the fact it's a constant and use it as if it was an identifier.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . And you can continue:  "in an `ORDER BY` clause but pretty much no where else."

Comment: @gordon AFAIK you are correct. I didn't see it work in any other clause.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is using an alias in the having clause working?

`'aaaaaa'` is not an alias but string literal.

```
having count('aaaaaa') > 10
-- same as
       count(*)
       count(1) 
       count(GETDATE())
```

As long as expression isn't  `NULL` then COUNT will work properly.

Comment: I know that 'aaaaaa' is a string literal. But when I use the alias, having count('TotalProducts') > 10 it is correctly returning the proper group filter, only categorynames that have a product id count greater than 10. This should be false, 1 is not greater than 10

Comment: @James `having count('TotalProducts') > 10` It is not an alias but string literal. Second you cannot refer to column defined at `SELECT` in `HAVING`. You should use entire expression `having count(p.productid) > 10`

Comment: I agree, and that is the way I normally do it. But it seems it is working regardless, using count('TotalProducts')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to the line currently commented out in the code you've posted - the `p` alias was used in the `from` clause - that means you can use it in any other clause in the query - including sub queries, having clause, and even apply clauses and join clauses.

This is not true when using an alias in the `select` clause - these aliases can only be used on the `order by` clause.

```
select
c.categoryname,
count(p.productid) as 'TotalProducts'
from Production.Products p

left join Production.Categories c

-- both `p` and `c` aliases are valid here since they where introduced in the `from` and `join` clauses
on p.categoryid = c.categoryid

-- the use of `c` here is valid since it was introduced in the `join` clause
group by c.categoryname

-- the use of `p` here is valid since `p` was introduced in the `from` clause.
having count(p.productid) > 10 

-- This, however, will cause an error - invalid column name `TotalProducts`
-- having count(TotalProducts) > 10 

-- This is valid since TotalProducts is an alias introduced in the `select` clause.
order by 'TotalProducts' desc;
```

Comment: I am aware of logical query processing order and aliases. I would expect only the order by clause to work with the alias since the order by comes after the select. but for some reason the having clause is not returning an error when using having count('TotalProducts') > 10. if I use it without the single apostrophe delimiter I get an error, but if I use it with the single apostrophe it returns the correct result. isn't count('TotalProducts') really just equal to 1?

Comment: How is it answered? How is count(1) > 10? This should return no rows. Instead it returns all categories that have a product id count > 10

Comment: select count(1) returns 1. the Expression Having count(1) > 10 is like saying having 1>10. when is 1 ever greater than 10? I guess I'm confused. the predicate is false, no rows should be returned the way I am thinking of ot

Comment: No. The expresstion `count(1)` returns the number of rows in each group. It does not return 1 unless the specific group contains just one row